# generating 14 digits based on the following

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a database application. The user will enter his/her particulars in a form. Once they click on the register button, those data fields will be stored in a database.

What i want to do is, once clicked on the register button, a 14 digits is generated an recorded in the database as the unique identifier key. Those digits are based on the last 2 digit of the current registration year, his/her birth date which is 8 digits, a serial number start at 1 (leaded by two zeros eg 001, 001)which increment by one every time the register button is clicked, and lastly a check digit.

eg 15071990110014

```
   Private id As Integer

Public Function generateUniqueNumber() As Long
    id += 1
    Dim curDate As Date = DateTime.Today
    Dim regYear As Integer = curDate.Year.ToString.Substring(2)

    Dim dob As Integer = CInt(BirthDate)
    Dim vID As String = id.ToString("D3")
    Dim uniqueID As String = regYear & dob & vID


    Dim r, sum As Integer
    While uniqueID <> 0
        r = uniqueID Mod 10
        sum += r
        uniqueID \= 10
    End While


    Dim checkDigit As Decimal = 0
    Dim reminder As Decimal = 0

    reminder = sum Mod 10
    If reminder = 0 Then
        checkDigit = 0
    Else
        checkDigit = 10 - reminder
    End If

    Dim uid As String = regYear & dob & vID & checkDigit


    Return uid
End Function
```

Comment: Can I post my code, it doesn't work properly

Comment: that is a very good reason **for** posting your code - much easier to fix code we can see

Comment: Done! This code is ineffective

Comment: Are you returning a string as a long?

Comment: ChicagoMike, conversion is done implicitly. I know this is a bad habit, but all what I want now is the increment to work. Every time I call this function the code returned remains the same. Even though it should increment by 1.

Comment: Depending on how it is used, encoding data into some sort of ID is usually a bad idea.  You will have oodles of code elsewhere to tear these apart to get at the sub elements, for instance the sequential ID so you know what to increment next time.

Comment: Look into GUID - unique ID is its intended purpose.

Comment: If you fix all those implicit conversions that you want to skip over - use `Option Strict On` - it actually does work.  Too many digits are getting lost in the conversions...`CInt(BirthDate)`

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks anyways. I've been trying for two days before i post it in here...

Comment: @VBCoder In what way *exactly* does it not work? You could use `Static id As Integer = 0` *inside* the function, however you would need to retrieve the latest serial number from the database to initialise it correctly. Also, it should be `Dim regYear As String = (curDate.Year Mod 100).ToString("00")` if you want the last two digits of the year as a two-character string.

Comment: any database worthy of the name will have an autoincrement/identity type specifically for unique IDs

Answer (score 0):

Here are some snippets that may help.

DOB is formatted as a consistent string with leading zeros on month and day. id is padded. You'll need to add the code to tweak the id and do the check digit.

```
    Dim regYear As String = Now.Year.ToString.Substring(2)
    Dim dob As String =Format(CDate("01/01/1990"), "MMddyyyy")
    Dim vID As String = id.ToString.PadLeft(3, "0")
    Dim uniqueID As String = regYear & dob & vID
```